# Using SSRS Report viewer how do I bind/link two objects?

Tags: reporting-services, textbox, linker, report, overlay

How do I link two objects using SSRS reporting? 
I would like a text box (with only border filled in) to appear over some of the data as i've placed it in design mode. (see graphic). 
[image]

However, my rectangular box seems to be moving down below the series of data.

[image]

I had to block out some of the language but I can't figure out how to move the box. It should overlay part of the expression/text box.

Thank you,

Comment: Is this in the page header? If not, Tablix is a better way to control field layouts, and you can use borders to make an outside border. If you must use a rectangle, drag the data objects into the rectangle to make it the container.

Comment: This goes into the header section, but no its the body of the report. The thing is I need the rectangle to cover only part of the data. Basically the user would like a portion of the data highlighted. (with a box).

Comment: Should be able to drag textboxes into the rectangle to make it the container.

Comment: Yes, I will try that. But my issue is that my data grows and shrinks and I need the text box to grow/shrink with it.

Comment: It's in the header growing? Hmm. If you can get it into the body, draw a border around those cells, problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, SSRS draws the first text box then moves the next one down when it tries to draw the next. It assumes you don't want to overlap.

You might be better off using 4 LINES to create your box. Lines are not affected by other objects in the report renderer. You may encounter issues when exporting though.

You could also create separate text boxes for each item and value (10 total - 2 wide by 5 high) and using the border properties to highlight the 3 rows in the middle.

Another way to do what you want is to create a 2 x 5 static table with no dataset and placing each of your elements in it's own cell. Then you can use the border properties to create your box.

Comment: I learned as much, it's a bit frustrating as I want to have a report with certain layouts and overlapping data elements.